# How do I add a digital signature to an Infopath form in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, infopath, sharepoint-addin, digital-signature

How to add a digital signature to Infopath form. You need to have a Infopath filler but that is not what resides in SharePoint. Is there a way to add a digital signature line?

Answer (score 1):

The build-in digital signature control provided by InfoPath only works when using the InfoPath Filler application.  SharePoint does not support displaying that control in a web-based InfoPath form.

If you want to use digital signature with SharePoint, you will need to use third-party tools, such a CoSign.

Answer (score 1):

[Disclosure: I work for CoSign]

CoSign by ARX is the strongest digital signature solution with millions of signers around the world. CoSign provides a solution for SharePoint that enables signing documents within SharePoint.

In order to add a digital signature line to an InfoPath form you must use InfoPAth desinger.
With CoSign solution for SharePoint you can digitally sign InfoPath web forms.

For additional information please contact support@arx.com or visit our website http://www.arx.com/digital-signature/sharepoint

For information about how signing an InfoPath please visit http://www.arx.com/flash/Digital-Signatures-InfoPath